# Synthesize VHDL into discrete TTL integrated circuits

Tags: vhdl, ttl, education, synthesis

I've got a small project in VHDL (fully working in a Xilinx FPGA) and I would like to implement it using an old-school printed circuit board and discrete TTL integrated circuits, in the spirit of projects such as [TTL Clock](http://www.ttlclock.com/), for educational / entertaining purposes.

Which (preferrably free software / open source) tools can help me in this project? Suggestions capable of minimizing the number of chips (not necessarily the number of gates!) and generating the PCB layout are very welcome, too.

Comment: You will need to find a synthesis engine.  There is Icarus Verilog which apparently does synthesis.  I haven't used it and I don't know of any VHDL open source versions.  Additionally you'll need the SDF file format for the cells and library you are targeting.  This gives the functionality and timing of the available cells.  That is the way that one synthesis engine can map to different libraries and devices (FPGA's have a very different structure than ASICS for example)  Once you've generated a netlist from the synthesis,  You can then place and Route it. Probably EDIF format.

Answer (score 4):

The [Free Model Foundry](http://www.freemodelfoundry.com/fmf_VHDL_models.php) has a [74 Series TTL library](http://www.freemodelfoundry.com/stnd.php) in VHDL. I haven't ever had a use for it, but it might be a way to test a design idea before digging out the wire-wrap gun!

Answer (score 2):

Such synthesis tool is very unlikely to exist. I would consider taking the design and re-implementing it gradually in blocks that are equivalent to 74xxx parts.